# Crontab is overwritten by HiveOS on boot

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I am trying to add some additional cronjobs to a rig running on HiveOS. Every time I add a job to crontab (for example one for duckdns) it disappears after the reboot. I've noticed that the crontab contains some lines that are used for HiveOS, so I assume that HiveOS overwrites the crontab on startup.

Is it possible to run cronjobs without the lines being overwriten by HiveOS on the next restart?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which crontab are you using? Is it `/etc/crontab`? You could place it into `/var/spool/cron/tabs`. You would normally do `crontab -e` and edit as per any other crontab file.

Comment: I use crontab -e and the changes are saved, but when I reboot the file looks like before I edited it.

Comment: I would raise a bug, that should just not happen.

Comment: Theoretically HiveOS is not meant to be changed, so I think they overwrite the crontab without thinking that someone could add something there. Is there any possibility to start some jobs other then crontab -e?

Comment: Welcome, what about placing your contrabs under `/etc/cron.d` directory?

Comment: If it's not meant to be changed, but you are changing it, should you not be looking at another distro?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new job using the user `user` instead `root` and work just fine for me:

1st step

> crontab -e -u user

2nd step (for instance)

> */30 * * * * /hive/sbin/inetmonit.sh

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change cron jobs in the Hive OS env, go change it in the /hive/etc/crontab.root file with `nano` or other editor!

This is where the file is copied from and why your changes with `crontab -e` aren't working!

Side note : adding files in `/etc/cron.d` didn't work, it's not getting started.